# LAMP Server not executing PHP scripts properly

Tags: php, html, linux, apache, server

I have a LAMP(Ubuntu) Server running on a physical machine. My goal is to host a website on the server. Right now, I have all my files in my /var/www/html directory and inside certain HTML files, I run PHP scripts to check if the user is logged in or not such as below:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id = "navCollapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active link-nav"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li class="link-nav"><a href="/pages/categories/">Categories</a></li>
        <li class="link-nav"><a href="/pages/about/">About</a></li>


        <!-- This part -->
        <?php
            if($_SESSION['loggedin'] != 1){
                echo '<li class="link-nav">
                    <a href="#login" data-toggle="modal"> Log In</a>
                </li>
                <li class="link-nav">
                    <a href="#register" data-toggle="modal"> Register</a>
                </li>';
            }else{
                echo "<li class = 'link-nav'><a href="logout.php"> Log Out </a>";                       
            }
        ?>

        <!-- End of PHP -->

    </ul>
</div>
```

When I open up to my server in the browser, all I get is this:

[image: Bug in PHP]

The `$_SESSION['loggedin']` variable has already been set but both the Login and Logout buttons show. Also, the text in between the two sets of strings is showing on the page.

When I display this on my local computer using XAMPP, this doesn't happen.

Any ideas on how to fix this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This doesn't happen in XAMPP on my local computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is invalid. With proper error reporting on, you would see the error. When testing, it will help a lot to have error reporting turned on so you can see the helpful errors :)

```
echo "<li class = 'link-nav'><a href="logout.php"> Log Out </a>";
```

You can not use the double quotes inside themselves without escaping them!

Instead write it like this:

```
echo '<li class="link-nav"><a href="logout.php">Log Out</a>';
```

See if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, It's much easier to work with code that has islands rather than everything being a PHP string(Also, take a look at http://www.Laravel.com and http://www.Laracasts.com):

```
<?php if($_SESSION['loggedin'] != 1){ ?>
    <li class="link-nav">
        <a href="#login" data-toggle="modal"> Log In</a>
    </li>
    <li class="link-nav">
        <a href="#register" data-toggle="modal"> Register</a>
    </li>
<?php }else{ ?>
    <li class="link-nav"><a href="logout.php"> Log Out </a>                       
<?php } ?>
```